# Flutter: With [just audio], is it possible to create a playlist that doesn't automatically jump to the next audio when the current finishes?

Tags: flutter, just-audio

I'm using [Flutter just audio](https://github.com/ryanheise/just_audio/tree/minor/just_audio) and I'm creating a `ContatenatingAudioSource` like this:

```
// Define the playlist
final playlist = ConcatenatingAudioSource(
  // Start loading next item just before reaching it
  useLazyPreparation: true,
  // Customise the shuffle algorithm
  shuffleOrder: DefaultShuffleOrder(),
  // Specify the playlist items
  children: [
    AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse('https://example.com/track1.mp3')),
    AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse('https://example.com/track2.mp3')),
    AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse('https://example.com/track3.mp3')),
  ],
);
```

This works perfectly, but I can't seem to prevent the next audio from playing when the current one ends.

All I want is a playlist where I have to explicitly `seek` the next audio, whenever the current one ends.

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like `ConcatenatingAudioSource` is not the right solution to your problem, because what it does is "concatenate" the audio of multiple items together so that they can be played continuously.

If all you want is to have separate items that the user can switch between, then you can program it exactly that way:

```dart
final items = [
  AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse('https://example.com/track1.mp3')),
  AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse('https://example.com/track2.mp3')),
  AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse('https://example.com/track3.mp3')),
];


Future<void> selectItem(int index) {
  await player.setAudioSource(items[index]!);
}
```

Now, there is only ever one item in just_audio's playlist which means that when it completes, it completes. You can call `selectItem(i)` to switch to item `i`.

This solution does mean that `player.sequence` will not contain a sequence of all items, it will only ever contain a single item. So if you were relying on that to render the list in your UI, you should instead use `items` (declared above).

Comment: Oh you are the developer! :). Thanks a lot, it indeed works. If you know, off the top of your head, how to make `AudioSource` to download and cache in the background, instead of waiting, I would appreciate. Thanks for developing this amazing lib

Comment: If what you're asking is something different from `LockCachingAudioSource`, then you may need to make a feature request on the GitHub page.